# The choice of which html element to show in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

How to choose in AngularJS which html element to show? I'm getting the value of some element from database and if it is YES I want to show this: `<i class="fa fa-check"></i>` or if NO this: `<i class="fa fa-times"></i>`

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using **[ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)**

Try like this

```
<i class="fa fa-check" ng-class="{'fa-check' : myModel=='YES' , 'fa-times' : myModel=='NO' }"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="ExampleController">

<head>
  <title>stackoverflow</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-show="dataFromDataBase">
    view A
  </div>

  <div ng-hide="dataFromDataBase">
    view B
  </div>

  <button ng-click="change()">return false/true</button>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.js"></script>

  <script>
    //https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.js
    angular.module("app", [])
      .controller("ExampleController", ["$scope",
        function($scope) {

          $scope.dataFromDataBase = true; // or false

          $scope.change = function() {
            $scope.dataFromDataBase ? $scope.dataFromDataBase = false : $scope.dataFromDataBase = true;
          }
        }
      ])
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your database value to scope attributed anything. for eg: `model` and use [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) and [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) directives to show/ hide the html

```
<i ng-show="model" class="fa fa-check"></i> or if NO this: <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
<i ng-hide="model" class="fa fa-check"></i> or if NO this: <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
```